# How do you retrieve the information from a foreign key in python sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite3.

So in python, I want to be able to use a WHERE clause to access the information on the database. Since the foreign key(GenreID) information is in the Genre table, how am I able to display the genre name with just the ID. I have been looking for a lot of solutions but none of them worked. I tried .lastrowid but that didn't work.

Since there are multiple genres in a movie, I want to be able to just us the IDs

The pictures below are the two tables - Left is Genre. Right is Shows

[image][image]

Comment: `SELECT Shows.*, Genre.GenreName FROM Shows, Genre WHERE Shows.GenreID = Genre.ID;`

Comment: I'll try it out. Can you please explain what this line does because I would like to change this in the future for a similar module

Comment: Or, `SELECT Shows.*, Genre.GenreName FROM Shows INNER JOIN Genre ON Shows.GenreID = Genre.ID;`

Comment: Well, that's basic SQL syntax.  A SELECT can draw columns from many different tables.  You just have to tell it how to combine them with the WHERE clause.